# Magento: How to decline order when total due > 0

Tags: magento

- Customer XYZ made an order 1234 for a total of $83.00 + $15 Shipping = $98.00
- A $65 voucher was used and a $10 off promo (TAKE10) was used.
- Remaining total was $23.00
- Customer then went though checkout however was only charged $16.01 on her credit card
- Order then completed in the system and become a processing order even though a $6.99 balance was still remaining to be paid - [See screen shot](http://i.gyazo.com/85c73bb885a4428dc131d7fcf88e4a6e.png)

How to: Order should of declined or charged the full amount of $23.00
Please help me.

Comment: Was this order created in the admin?

Comment: Yes, the order was created

Comment: If you did not follow a good order of operations in the admin panel when creating this order,  you could have ended up charging the card prior to clicking submit on the discount code.